# When is a command's compile function called?

Tags: tcl

My understanding of TCL execution is, if a command's compile function is defined, it is first called when it comes to execute the command before its execution function is called.

Take command append as example, here is its definition in tclBasic.c:

```
static CONST CmdInfo builtInCmds[] = {

    {"append",          (Tcl_CmdProc *) NULL,   Tcl_AppendObjCmd,
        TclCompileAppendCmd,            1},
```

Here is my testing script:

```
$ cat t.tcl
set l [list 1 2 3]
append l 4
```

I add gdb breakpoints at both functions, TclCompileAppendCmd and Tcl_AppendObjCmd. My expectation is TclCompileAppendCmd is hit before Tcl_AppendObjCmd.

Gdb's target is tclsh8.4 and argument is t.tcl.

What I see is interesting:

1. TclCompileAppendCmd does get hit first, but it is not from t.tcl,
   rather it is from init.tcl.
2. TclCompileAppendCmd gets hit several times and they all are from init.tcl.
3. The first time t.tcl executes, it is Tcl_AppendObjCmd gets hit, not TclCompileAppendCmd.

I cannot make sense of it:

1. Why is the compile function called for init.tcl but not for t.tcl?
2. Each script should be independently compiled, i.e. the object with compiled command append at init.tcl is not reused for later scripts, isn't it?

**[UPDATE]**
Thanks [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930666/brad-lanam) for the tip, after I move the script to a proc, I can see TclCompileAppendCmd is hit.

Comment: Try putting your test inside of a proc.  Q2 has some sort of wrong assumption.  The `append` command is compiled.

Comment: It is one of the quirks of the Tcl bytecode compiler.   Generally speaking, once a script starts getting long, create a main procedure and put everything in it so that it gets compiled.

Comment: The exception are with the very large scripts found in EDA tools. Those run up against some horrible memory limits...

Answer (score 0):

The compilation function (`TclCompileAppendCmd` in your example) is called by the bytecode compiler when it wants to issue bytecode for a particular instance of that particular command. The bytecode compiler also has a fallback if there is no compilation function for a command: it issues instructions to invoke the standard implementation (which would be `Tcl_AppendObjCmd` in this case; the `NULL` in the other field causes Tcl to generate a thunk in case someone *really* insists on using a particular API but you can ignore that). That's a useful behaviour, because it is how operations like I/O are handled; the overhead of calling a standard command implementation is pretty small by comparison with the overhead of doing disk or network I/O.

But when does the bytecode compiler run?

On one level, it runs whenever the rest of Tcl asks for it to be run. Simple! But that's not really helpful to you. More to the point, it runs whenever Tcl evaluates a script value in a `Tcl_Obj` that doesn't already have bytecode type (or if the saved bytecode indicates that it is for a different resolution context or different compilation epoch) ***except if the evaluation has asked to not be bytecode compiled*** by the flag `TCL_EVAL_DIRECT` to `Tcl_EvalObjEx` or `Tcl_EvalEx` (which is a convenient wrapper for `Tcl_EvalObjEx`). It's that flag which is causing you problems.

When is that flag used?

It's actually pretty simple: it's used when some code is believed to be going to be run only once because then the cost of compilation is larger than the cost of using the interpretation path. It's *particularly* used by Tk's `bind` command for running substituted script callbacks, but it is also used by `source` and the main code of `tclsh` (essentially anything using `Tcl_FSEvalFileEx` or its predecessors/wrappers `Tcl_FSEvalFile` and `Tcl_EvalFile`). I'm not 100% sure whether that's the right choice for a `source`d context, but it is what happens now. However, there is a workaround that is (highly!) worthwhile if you're handling looping: you can put the code in a compiled context within that `source` using a procedure that you call immediately or use an `apply` (I recommend the latter these days). `init.tcl` uses these tricks, which is why you were seeing it compile things.

And no, we don't normally save compiled scripts between runs of Tcl. Our compiler is fast enough that that's not really worthwhile; the cost of verifying that the loaded compiled code is correct for the current interpreter is high enough that it's actually faster to recompile from the source code. Our current compiler is *fast* (I'm working on a slower one that generates enormously better code). There's a commercial tool suite from ActiveState (the Tcl Dev Kit) which includes an ahead-of-time compiler, but that's focused around shrouding code for the purposes of commercial deployment and not speed.

Comment: My answer strictly pertains to 8.5 and 8.6, but is pretty transferrable to 8.4